# Why 16-bit compiler gives error for unsingned char[] declaration?

Tags: c++, 16-bit

Here is code:

```
unsigned char A[] = { 'a', 'b', 12, 256, 'c', 28 };
```

it compiles well in VS using x64 compiler. But 16-bit compiler gives some error and unfortunately I don't know what kind of error. The question is why 16-bit gives error in this case. Can you explain it?

Comment: 256 sounds familiar

Comment: 256 is outside of representable range.

Comment: Why don't you know what kind of error?

Comment: Post the error message. Without it the “answers” you’ve gotten are just guesses.

Comment: Which C++ compiler? Turbo-C++? Watcom? something else? Is this the line with the error?  MSVC 64-bit gives a warning.  My version Turbo-C++ doesn't warn or error out.

Comment: Maybe post your entire piece of code? I'm thinking the problem is something else or there is more to it than what you are showing

Answer (score 1):

A `char` is always a byte, so whether your platform is 16-bit or 64-bit words doesn't really matter (though if you're using a system with `CHAR_BIT != 8`, we'll talk!). What's probably of more consequence is that your 16-bit compiler (yes, I'm assuming Turbo C++) is from the 1980s, a decade before the first *standard* edition of C++, so it behaves a bit differently overall.

In this case, it is less tolerant of the value `256`, which is actually larger than can be stored in a `char` (signed or otherwise). I'd say it's "wrong", but it's hard to be non-compliant to a standard that didn't exist at the time. Turbo C++ is pretty much free to do its own thing, in that sense — it's not *actually* C++, in the way that we understand the term "C++" today.

I would expect your Visual Studio compiler to emit a compiler warning... and then initialise the `unsigned char` using *wraparound*, as that's how unsigned values work.

Comment: In TC++'s defence, I don't actually remember how strict the C++ rules are about this kind of narrowing initialisation and it could be that VS is being permissive

Comment: its c++ Jim, but not as we know it

Comment: @pm100: "how quaint"